# Hide UIPageControl

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, user-interface

i want to hide the bar of the UIPageControl, because i want to implement a pagination with swipe gesture function so I don't need to display the dot bar. If I set `hidden=YES` there will remain a black block with size of the UIPageControl. Is there a way to hide the UIPageControl Bar completely?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20749979/654870

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a black box because there is no other view covering that area. Resize your other views and there will be content.

By the way, there is no way we can guess what project or page control you are talking about.

If you don't need a page control, then you shouldn't add it in the first place. It is still there, even if hidden.

Comment: Thanks, i'm a fool^^ Didn't see that my scrollview isn't fullscreen.